# How can I get all the data in flatMapGroup in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a scenario in which we need to calculate 'charges' for a stream of events which has the following details:

```
1. Event contains eventTime, facet, units
2. Free quantity per facet that needs to offset the earliest events based on the eventTime
3. Prices are also specified per facet
4. Events that arrive in a single minute can be considered equivalent (for reduced state maintenance) and all of them need to have free units proportionally distributed
```

I was hoping to make it the work in the following manner using spark structured streaming

```
1. Aggregate events at a minute level per facet using the window function per facet
2. Join with the price and free quantity
3. Group by facet
4. flatMapGroup by facet to then sort the aggregation by window start time, apply the results
```

what I am noticing is that the output of #4 is just the aggregation for which new events came in and not all the aggregation since the watermark. 
**Qn: How can I fix this code to get all aggregation since the watermark?**

Could someone help?
Thanks

```
package test

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.UUID
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{GroupState, GroupStateTimeout, OutputMode, Trigger}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

case class UsageEvent(Id: String, facetId: String, Units: Double, timeStamp:Timestamp)
case class FacetPricePoints(facetId: String, Price: Double, FreeUnits: Double)
case class UsageBlock(facetId: String, start:Timestamp, Units: Double)
case class UsageBlockWithPrice(facetId: String, start:Timestamp, Units: Double, Price: Double, FreeUnits: Double)
case class UsageBlockWithCharge(facetId: String, start:Timestamp, Units: Double, Price: Double, FreeUnits: Double, ChargedUnits: Double, Charge: Double)

object TestProcessing {
  def getUsageEventStream(ts: Timestamp, units: String) : UsageEvent = {UsageEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString, "F1", units.toInt % 20, ts)}
  implicit def ordered: Ordering[Timestamp] = new Ordering[Timestamp] {def compare(x: Timestamp, y: Timestamp): Int = x compareTo y}
  def ChargeUsageBlock(Key: String, Value: Iterator[UsageBlockWithPrice]) : Iterator[UsageBlockWithCharge] =
  {
    val usageBlocks = Value.toList.sortBy(ub => ub.start)
    var freeUnits = 0.0
    var freeUnitsSet = false
    var newUe = for (ue <- usageBlocks)
      yield {
        freeUnits = if (!freeUnitsSet) ue.FreeUnits else freeUnits
        freeUnitsSet = true
        val freeUnitsInBlock = if (freeUnits > ue.Units) ue.Units else freeUnits
        val chargedUnits = ue.Units - freeUnitsInBlock
        freeUnits -= freeUnitsInBlock // todo: need to specify precision and rounding
        UsageBlockWithCharge(ue.facetId, ue.start, ue.Units, ue.Price, freeUnitsInBlock, chargedUnits, chargedUnits * ue.Price)
      }
    newUe.iterator
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    val stream = spark.readStream.format("rate").option("rowsPerSecond", 1).load()
    import spark.implicits._
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
    val prices = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(List( FacetPricePoints("F1", 30.0, 100.0))).toDF()

    val getUsageEventStreamUDF = udf((ts: Timestamp, units: String) => getUsageEventStream(ts, units)) // .where($"Units" < 2).
    val usageEventsRaw = stream.withColumn("Usage", getUsageEventStreamUDF(stream("timestamp"), stream("value"))).select("Usage.*").as[UsageEvent].dropDuplicates("Id").withWatermark("timeStamp", "1 hour")
    val aggUsage = usageEventsRaw.groupBy($"facetId", window($"timeStamp", "1 minute")).agg(sum($"Units") as "Units").selectExpr("facetId", "window.start", "Units").as[UsageBlock]
    val fifoRate = (Key: String, Value: Iterator[UsageBlockWithPrice]) => { ChargeUsageBlock(Key, Value) }
    val aggUsageCharge = aggUsage.joinWith(prices, prices.col("facetId") === usageEventsRaw.col("facetId")).select("_1.*", "_2.Price", "_2.FreeUnits").as[UsageBlockWithPrice].groupByKey(x => x.facetId).flatMapGroups(fifoRate).withWatermark("start", "1 hour")
    val fin = aggUsageCharge.writeStream.trigger((Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))).outputMode(OutputMode.Update).format("console").start()
                // this applies freeUnits for every minute instead of just applying it once
    fin.awaitTermination()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```